# Need to require a Postgres user on AWS RDS to login with password

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a new Postgres database on RDS. I have set up the database to be Publicly Accessible so we can login via ssh. However we can do so without supplying a password. I want to force the user to have to login with a password.

All of my searches for solutions recommend editing .pgpass file but I don't think this applies to a Postgres database on RDS.

If anyone know how to do this I would greatly appreciate the help

Comment: How can you do so without a password? Postgres users have a password, do you mean you want a password on the ssh connection?

Comment: @tedder42 I'm logging in via psql and although the user does have a password it is currently not required. I want the psql to prompt the user to enter the password in order to successfully login.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS Postgres RDS does not support password-less login via a database parameter group change e.g. by turning on Trust Authentication.

If you are not being prompted for a password when using psql, you must be using a .pgpass file locally. You can confirm this by temporarily removing that file or renaming the file and then trying to connect; you should be prompted for a password.